TypeScript: Unexpected behavior with 'satisfies' operator and optional properties
I'm encountering some unexpected behavior with TypeScript's satisfies operator when dealing with optional properties and the Record type. Here's a minimal example that demonstrates the issue:
// Type set up

type T = Record<string, number>;

type X = {
  inner?: number | undefined;
};

type Y = {
  inner: number | undefined;
};


// Example 1

function f(x: X, y: Y) {
  y satisfies X; // no type error (expected)

  x satisfies T; // no type error, but why? undefined is not assignable to number

  y satisfies T;
  // type error (expected):
  // Type 'Y' does not satisfy the expected type 'T'.
  // Property 'inner' is incompatible with index signature.
  //   Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  //     Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(1360)
}


// Example 2

const x = { inner: undefined };
x satisfies X; // no type error (expected)
x satisfies T; // type error (expected)

const y: { inner?: number | undefined } = x;
y satisfies X; // no type error (expected)
y satisfies T; // no type error, but why?

It seems like type X should not be compatible with type T, given the instance { inner: undefined }.

With normal compiler options, TS doesn't very strictly separate the concepts of "missing" and "present-but-undefined" for properties, as per ms/TS#13195. If you care about this you can enable the --exactOptionalProperties compiler option as shown in this playground link, but it's not part of the --strict suite of options because it breaks a lot of stuff. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?
